# Docker-compose: Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent

Tags: docker, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, google-compute-engine

I am trying my first steps with Docker and Google Cloud engine and I am not able to run the docker virtually on Google Cloud after pulling it from docker-hub even it runs locally on Docker desktop. Can someone tell me why?

I always run into this error:

```
docker-compose up
ERROR: 
      Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
      parent. Are you in the right directory?
    
      Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

I always execute the following steps:

1. I created this docker file:

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/server
WORKDIR /usr/src/server
COPY package.json /usr/src/server/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/server
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

2. I created this docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: cloudcomputing2023/cloudcomputinggroup222:latest
    container_name: cloudcomputinggroup222
    depends_on:
      - "mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/booksData
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongodb"
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/data/db
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

3. And this the the index.js file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGODB_URI ||
    "mongodb://localhost:27017/booksData",{ useNewUrlParser: true });

console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
module.exports.books = require("./books.js");
```

**4. Then I start Docker Desktop with Docker Daemon (windows locally) and it works locally.**

5. Docker Hub login

```
Docker login
```

6. Then I change the directory to the directory with the docker-compose.yml file locally
7. I build the image and start the container with docker-compose

```
 docker-compose up
```

**It works fine locally.**

8. I tag the image and the docker-hub

```
docker tag 502fc5d0b07aea2126be8257427d099379f6a6e0fb31e3eaf008c2c7d582e09c cloudcomputing2023/cloudcomputinggroup222:latest
```

9. I push the images to docker-hub

```
docker push cloudcomputing2023/cloudcomputinggroup222:latest
```

9. The push works and it shows the following image layers on docker-hub

```
ADD file ... in /
3.22 MB
2
CMD ["/bin/sh"]
0 B
3
ENV NODE_VERSION=20.1.0
0 B
4
/bin/sh -c addgroup -g 1000
47.25 MB
5
ENV YARN_VERSION=1.22.19
0 B
6
/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache
2.24 MB
7
COPY file:4d192565a7220e135cab6c77fbc1c73211b69f3d9fb37e62857b2c6eb9363d51 in /usr/local/bin/
451 B
8
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
0 B
9
CMD ["node"]
0 B
10
RUN /bin/sh -c mkdir -p
138 B
11
WORKDIR /usr/src/server
32 B
12
COPY package.json /usr/src/server/ # buildkit
460 B
13
RUN /bin/sh -c npm install
7.84 MB
14
COPY . /usr/src/server # buildkit
15.47 KB
15
EXPOSE map[3000/tcp:{}]
0 B
16
CMD ["node" "server.js"]
0 B
run code snippetVisit Manage Class to disable runnable code snippets×
```

10. I login in google cloud platform and create a virtual machine with  the following configuration

```
n2-ubuntu-20-4-http-https-SSD
```

11. I install docker and it outputs the following version

```
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.6
 API version:       1.42
 Go version:        go1.19.9
 Git commit:        ef23cbc
 Built:             Fri May  5 21:18:22 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.6
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.9
  Git commit:       9dbdbd4
  Built:            Fri May  5 21:18:22 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
```

12. I install docker compose and it outputs the following verion

```
docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown
docker-py version: 4.1.0
CPython version: 3.8.10
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

13. I login into Docker Hub on the virtual machine

```
Docker login
```

14. I pull the image from docker-hub

```
docker pull cloudcomputing2023/cloudcomputinggroup222:latest
```

15. I would like to use docker-compose up. But I receive an error saying that the file can't be found.

```
docker-compose up
ERROR: 
        Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

**Is that the issue? If so, why is it missing? How can I change the directory to the file? How can I output the file structure? Do I have to copy the file manually? If so, how do I do that on an ubuntu virtual machine?
What am I missing in my approach?**

If I try to run it, I receive a different network error:

```
docker run cloudcomputing2023/cloudcomputinggroup22:latest
Express server is up and running on http://localhost:3000/
/usr/src/server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441
          new MongoNetworkError(
          ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodb
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookupall [as oncomplete] (node:dns:119:26) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
run code snippetVisit Manage Class to disable runnable code snippets×
```

But If I type docker images it outputs my image on the virtual machine.

```
docker images
REPOSITORY                                  TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
cloudcomputing2023/cloudcomputinggroup222   latest    502fc5d0b07a   4 days ago    204MB
```

Which confuses me even more? Can I have an image without an compose file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the `docker-compose.yml` file, probably using `scp` (or maybe `git clone`).  It is not part of the image and it must exist independently on the host system.

You do not need to manually `docker pull` the image.  Compose will do that for you, in the same way it automatically pulls the `mongo:latest` image.  The image shows up in `docker images` because you manually pulled it.

There are other ways to run containers besides using Compose, most obviously `docker run`, and it's possible to have an image locally without having a valid local Compose setup.  You can be in the opposite situation as well, if you provision a new instance and `scp docker-compose.yml remote-system:` then you'll have the Compose file but not (yet) the images it runs.

Comment: Thank you. I somehow missed that the docker-compse.yml file must exist independently.